# assign value as per ratio defined

Tags: python, c, algorithm, math

I have one scenario here. Let me explain by small example.

I have 10 pens, I have to give it to 3 people. Those person's ratio are like 6:6:1 means if I am giving 1 pen to Person C I have to give 6-6 pens to Person A and Person B.

I have tried to solve it by using simple calculation which I have described below.

```
PerPersonPen = (TotalCountofPens * PerPersonRatio)/(SumofAllPersonsRatio) 

Person A =(Int) (10*6)/13 = 4
Person B = (Int) (10*6)/13 = 4
Person C = (Int) (10*1)/13 = 0
```

Here, Person C will get 0 pens, but it shouldn't happen. I would like that Person A & B are getting 4 pens, which are right. But Person C should get 1 pen also which remains.

This happens in a case of any person have 1 ratio count compare to others.

Can anybody help me to sort out this? Or How can I achieve it?

Comment: You may read : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118349/how-to-round-numbers-fairly. Scary at first, though.

Comment: I thought scenario is not here to divide pens equally between those three members, but at least one pen should given to one person at minimum level and pen should be divide according to PerPersonRatio.

Comment: More practically, you could use rounding instead of truncating, while starting to attribute to the least demanding first, revising the left total betwen each turn.

Comment: We can't use round because if we will use round then it will distribute pens like Person A - 5, Person B - 5, Person C - 1. While total we have only 10 pens. @LaurentG

Comment: That's why I mentionned "revising the left total".

Comment: I am not able to figure out what you are telling, can u please provide logic that how can I implement what you have suggested? @LaurentG

Comment: You have a rest of 2 pens `10 - (4+4)`. The rests per person are: `A=(10*6)%13=8` `B=(10*6)%13=8` and `C=(10*1)%13=10` giving 26 which is  `2 pens * SumofAllPersonsRatio` Now you must find how to divide 2 in a 8:8:10 ratio. But you see, Person C will get at first....

Comment: What do you want the answer to be, in this case (diving `13` items in ratio `6:6:1`)? Following the algo @LaurentG linked to (and implemented), you get `5 4 1`. Are you happy with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple method is to maintain a count of how many pens each person should get. Then, as long as they are pens to distribute, you give one to the person which should get the most pens.

Here is a work through of your example:

> **60/13**, 60/13, 10/13 -> **1**, 0, 0
>
> 47/13, **60/13**, 10/13 -> 1, **1**, 0
>
> **47/13**, 47/13, 10/13 -> **2**, 1, 0
>
> 34/13, **47/13**, 10/13 -> 2, **2**, 0
>
> **34/13**, 34/13, 10/13 -> **3**, 2, 0
>
> 21/13, **34/13**, 10/13 -> 3, **3**, 0
>
> **21/13**, 21/13, 10/13 -> **4**, 3, 0
>
> 8/13,  **21/13**, 10/13 -> 4, **4**, 0
>
> 8/13,  8/13,  **10/13** -> 4, 4, **1**
>
> **8/13**,  8/13,  -3/13 -> **5**, 4, 1

Comment: Hi, I tried your logic, but it fails in one of my trial cases. I have shared that case here. Please find it here: https://shrib.com/XWRx8nqQDYvtT2s

Comment: Can you please explain it that how can I achieve with given scenario in shared note link? @Antoine

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Laurent G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43134511/assign-value-as-per-ratio-defined#comment73346808_43134511) has given a very useful link to Math Stack Exchange in the comment section, [How to round numbers fairly](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118349/how-to-round-numbers-fairly)

This post implicitely suggests the following algorithm :

- For each person, compute the ratio `x_i` she should get (`x_i = her share/sum of shares`)
- Set `C_min = numberOfPens` and `C_max` large enough such that `sum_i (floor(x_i*C_max)) > numberOfPens` (`C_max = numberOfPens + 1/(min x_i)` should work)
- Do a dichotomic search between `C_min` and `C_max` until you find a `C` such that `sum_i (floor(x_i*C)) = numberOfPens`

This, however, might not work when there are ties (like in your example, where two ratios are of value 6/13). But what you can do is add a very little random noise (you add or substract less than half the smallest non-zero gap that exists between your original ratios) to your ratios to break ties and get a result in general, which will be "almost fair".

EDIT : I noticed that my initial choice of `C_max` was wrong, so I fixed it to something that works. However I think there is room for improvement. It is also possible to find the initial `C_max` by increasing `k` in `2^k numberOfPens` until the criterion (`sum_i(floor(x_i*C_max)) > numberOfPens`) is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at your example it is clear that each persone should get at least the rsult you calculated. 
And only some will get more.

I suggest the following algorithem:

1. calculate how much each presone should get in double. Same as you did without the cast.
2. sum the descrete sum of all persons (8 in our example).
3. Sort the persons by the Mantissa (After the point vaule).
4. For the first k persons Use `Math.Ceiling(assigned value)` where k is the desired value - sum we calculated in step 2. 10-8 in our example.
5. For the other persons use regular cast like `(int) (assigned value)`.

Answer (score -1):

Something like

```
int_weights = [6, 6, 1]
total_weights = sum(int_weights)

to_share = 10

still_to_share = to_share
left_weight_total = total_weights

shares = []
for weight in int_weights:
    s = int(0.5 + (float(still_to_share) * weight / left_weight_total))
    still_left -= s
    left_weight_total -= weight
    shares.append(s)
```

That gives quite but not absolutely fair (which can not be achieved with ties, cf the link I posted in comment of the Question)

```
shares
```

[5, 4, 1]

```
sum(shares)
```

0

If you want to achieve fairness to the ties, the best result would be `[4, 4, 2]` (or `[5, 5, 0]` [:auto_censored_but_not_totally:] ;-) ?) that you can reach by sorting and take into account previous allocation(s). Until I get to a good argument to be that picky I would keep with a solution like shown here-above.

Comment: You should give some brief at least for better understanding to other as well. @Laurent.

Comment: I like this principle from free software : the one that says do.
I try to use meaningful identifiers to allow reading code without redundant comments.
Thanks for the downvote;-)

Comment: Thank you downvoters \o/ By the end, I guess you will have turned me reasonable, absent. Go, go, go.